# Is there anything else I can do to deal with "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" running Ant (Command Line)?

Tags: java, android, ant

I'm trying to compile a *very* big, multi-project Android project using command line Ant. I was originally using Ant 1.8.3, but have since upgraded to 1.8.4 (in vain, it turns out). While I do have Eclipse installed (Indigo, updated today), the nature of this project precludes using Ant from within Eclipse for this.

The code seems to generate just fine, but when it gets to the "dex" phase of the operation it gets one of two errors, depending on my `ANT_OPTS`: "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" or "Java Heap Space".

I googled and checked Stack. After finding various links (c.f. [here](https://www.jfire.org/modules/phpwiki/index.php/Development%20Troubleshooting), [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html), [this Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148947/dojo-1-7-build-out-of-memory-errors), and [this stack question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288463/java-out-of-heap-space-error)), I modified my Ant options. (Many links cover what happens when this happens executing the Java code; my problem is actually in the Ant process that creates the Android APK for upload).

My `ANT_OPTS` environment variable is currently:

```
-Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xmn256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
```

I tried turning off the GC Overhead Limit altogether using `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`
, but all that does is give me a Java Heap Space error instead of the GC Overhead Limit error. I've asked my co-workers about this, but they're also out of ideas.

Oh, one more "detail": I can use Eclipse to compile and load the project, and that seems to work "just fine"; however, the sheer number of projects required for this "meta-project" suggests that I try to get the Ant script working.

**System Info:**

- OS: Windows 7 64 bit
- Java: Sun, 1.6, 64 bit
- Physical Memory: 8Gb
- Android: SDK Tools: R20; Platform Tools: R12 (Updated today, 28 Jun)

Is there something else I can do? Another keyword to search for? Someplace else to look?

Comment: I've no help to offer with your main question, but it might be useful for you to note that the build.xml in the tools\ant folder that is often imported by project build.xmls, has changed radically with Tools R20.

Comment: Actually, that might help. I'll have to see, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer to this one. Thanks goes to the current respondents, who helped me track this down.

There are, apparently, *two* (possibly three?) different places where the Java VM opts need to be changed, depending on exactly where the error occurs. In this case, the `ANT_OPTS` are *not* getting passed to Dex.

I was able to solve the error by editing the DX batch file, changing:

```
set defaultXmx=-Xmx1024M
```

to

```
set defaultXmx=-Xmx4096M
```

The **Obvious However**: I should never need to change the dx batch file. Anyone happen to know the "right" way to change the Java Options being passed to Dex by Ant?

Comment: From the dx script comments: `This can be overridden
# by using a "-J" option (see below)`.

Comment: The maxmemory attribute can also be used on the associated java tag:`<java jar="dx.jar" maxmemory="4096M">...</java>`

Comment: The irony is that Android development changed at least twice since I wrote this, so the question no longer applies to me. But perhaps it will be useful to someone else. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like what happens when an application slowly runs out of heap space.  If you have GC overhead limit set, the JVM dies fairly quickly.  If you don't, the application keeps going a bit longer, spending more and more time GC'ing ... and then finally dies.

If this was your application, you should check for storage leaks.  But since it is a well know and (presumably) well-tested 3rd party application, the simplest thing to try is ... to increase the heap size.

The other thing to try is to turn off CMS.  There is no reason to use CMS for a batch compilation: GC pauses are irrelevant.  Just use the throughput collector.  (This probably won't solve the heap size issue, but it should make your builds run faster.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's what I tried to turn off the GC Overhead Limit; all it did was shifted the error to the Java Heap. I'll edit to make that more clear.

Comment: Java Heaps can be made larger.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for wrong directories, invalid symbolic links, or missed files. For example, if your build.xml relies on a symbolic link that points to a folder that does not exist, the “GC Overhead Limit Exceeded” error may be triggered when in reality it doesn't has nothing to do with memory or garbage collection issue.